# Returning selected tklistbox value

Tags: r, tcl

**Question:**
How can I return the selected value from the tklistbox?

**Background:**
With tcltk library I want to get 3 inputs from the user.
Two of the inputs will be entered by the user, the 3rd one will be selected from the list.
However, the 3rd input returns as the list is.
Probably I'm making a dummy mistake but couldn't figure it out for a long time.

Thanks in advance...

**Mycode:**

```
inputs <- function(){
  
  ## GEOMETRY
  tt <- tktoplevel()
  tkwm.title(tt,"TITLE")
  tkwm.geometry(tt, "300x260+100+100")
  
  ### INPUTS
  ##########
  ## GETTING DATANAME
  data_headname <- tclVar("Giriniz")
  x.entry <- tkentry(tt, textvariable=data_headname, width=28, background="white")
  
  ## GETTING DATA DATE
  data_lastdate <- tclVar(as.character(Sys.Date()))
  y.entry <- tkentry(tt, textvariable=data_lastdate, width=28, background="white")

  ## GETTING ANALYSIS TYPE
  lvar <- tclVar()
  tclObj(lvar) <- c("Olcum Noktasi Azaltma", "Olcum Noktasi Tahminleme", "Hata Tahminleme")
  z.entry <- tklistbox(tt, listvariable=lvar, selectmode = "single", width=28, height=3, background="white")
  
  
  ### FUNCTIONS
  #############
  ## RESET
  reset <- function()
  {
    tclvalue(data_headname)<-"BOQP ADI"
    tclvalue(data_lastdate)<-"YYYY-AA-GG"
  }
  reset.but <- tkbutton(tt, text="SIFIRLA", command=reset)
  
  ## SUBMIT
  submit <- function() {
    x <- as.character(tclvalue(data_headname))
    y <- as.character(tclvalue(data_lastdate))
    z <- as.character(tclvalue(lvar))
    e <- parent.env(environment())
    e$x <- x
    e$y <- y
    e$z <- z
    tkdestroy(tt)
  }
  submit.but <- tkbutton(tt, text="TAMAM", command=submit)
  
  
  ### RETURN
  tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="\n   Lutfen Veri Bilgilerini ve Analizi Tipini Giriniz!   \n"),columnspan=2)
  tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="BQOP ADI   "), x.entry, pady = 10, padx =10)
  tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="VERI TARIHI"), y.entry, pady = 10, padx =10)
  tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="ANALIZ TIPI"), z.entry, pady = 10, padx =10)
  tkgrid(submit.but, reset.but)
  tkwait.window(tt)
  return(c(x,y,z))
}

myvals <- inputs()
myvals
```

[image: THE GUI]

**OUTPUT**
"A"
"B"
"{Olcum Noktasi Azaltma} {Olcum Noktasi Tahminleme} {Hata Tahminleme}"

**DESIRED OUTPUT**
"A"
"B"
"Hata Tahminleme"

Comment: In Tk, `.mylistbox curselection` returns the indices of the selections.

Comment: @BradLanam can you elaborate more please?

Comment: I don't know R.  But there should be something like z.entry.curselection to return the current selections.  Then use the returned index to access the text from lvar.